# What is the maximum and minimum distance between two points on different circles?

Tags: java, math, geometry

Suppose I have two circles with *(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>,r<sub>1</sub>)* and
*(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,r<sub>2</sub>)* as their coordinates and radius respectively. With this what is the maximum and minimum distance between them. What I have done till now:

```
double centreDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x[i] - x[j]), 2) + Math.pow((x[i] - y[j]), 2));
if (centreDistance >= r[i] + r[j]) {
    double maxDistance = centreDistance + (r[i] + r[j]);
    double minDistance = centreDistance - (r[i] + r[j]);
} else if (centreDistance == 0) {
    double minDistance = Math.abs(r[i] - r[j]);
    double maxDistance = Math.abs(r[i] - r[j]);
} else {
    int rmax = Math.max(r[i], r[j]);
    int rmin = Math.min(r[i], r[j]);
    double minDistance = rmax - (centreDistance + rmin);
    double maxDistance = rmax + (centreDistance - rmin);
}
```

Here x,y,r are arrays having x,y coordinates of center of each circle and radius respectively.This gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: the minimum distance is zero, since they can be at the same spot, the maximum distance is ... basically unmeasurable

Comment: @Stultuske I think OP means given the coordinates of the circles, what is the minimal/maximal distance between points on the circle.

Comment: Should `x[i]-y[j]` not be `y[i]-y[j]`?

Comment: I want the minimum and maximum distance for a given pair of circles. For disjoint circles the minimum distance is the distance between their centers minus the sum of their radii and maximum distance is distance between their centers plus the sum of their radii. I want my code to handle every possibility: disjoint circles, concentric circles, inner circles, etc.

Comment: ohh shit @TiiJ7 ...too stupid to not notice that one...I'll run it again to see if its right or not

Comment: @TiiJ7 something is still wrong in its implementation.

Comment: Tip: `double centreDistance = Math.hypot(x[i] - x[j]), y[i] - y[j]);` - use [hypotenuse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot(double,double))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The else path is wrong.

This:

```
double maxDistance = rmax + (centreDistance-rmin);
```

should be:

```
double maxDistance = rmax + centreDistance + rmin;
```

You are also missing the case where the circles intersect. This is the case when

```
centreDistance < r1+r2 && centredistance + rmin >= rmax
```

In that case

```
minDistance = 0 
maxDistance = rmax + centreDistance + rmin
```

centreDistance == 0 is also wrong, it should be maxDistance = `r1 + r2` (because you should compare points on opposite side of the center. In any case, it is just a special case of the else path and can be omitted.

The real case are:

```
centreDistance>=r[i]+r[j]       (centres are so far apart the circles don't overlap, or touch in one point)
centreDistance < r1+r2 && centredistance + rmin >= rmax        (circles intersect)
centreDistance < r1+r2 && centredistance + rmin < rmax        (one circle inside the other)
```

Comment: you are right in everything except that my first `if` condition also covers the case where circles just touch each other.

Comment: @Ryosuke You are right, I'll edit that part in the last list.

Comment: @Ryosuke Sooo, are you going to accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

in the case where the circle touch, you have to make some adjustments

```
if (centreDistance >= r[i] + r[j]) {
        // the circle dont touch, min and max distance are the closest and most far apart parts of the circles
        // code is correct
        double maxDistance = centreDistance + (r[i] + r[j]);
        double minDistance = centreDistance - (r[i] + r[j]);
    } else if (centreDistance == 0) {
        // the circle are on top of each other
        // check if they have the same radius -> max min dist = 0
        // if not max and min distance = Math.abs(r[i] - r[j]);
        // code is correct
        double minDistance = Math.abs(r[i] - r[j]);
        double maxDistance = Math.abs(r[i] - r[j]);
    } else {
        // the circles touch 
        // max distance is the same as in case where they dont touch
        // and min distance is 0 because they touch
        // code has to be adjusted
        int rmax = Math.max(r[i], r[j]);
        int rmin = Math.min(r[i], r[j]);
        double minDistance = rmax - (centreDistance + rmin);
        double maxDistance = rmax + (centreDistance - rmin);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `rmax` and `rmin` are integer. As you return the result of max and min it's rounded to an `int` value.